# Android Heads Up Firebase Notification not working

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have been stuck on this seemingly simple problem for 4 days now. I want to make my notifications in Android appear as a banner like they do in iOS, they are called Heads Up notifications i am told. After reviewing many posts i was under the impression i need to only set the priority to high and enable sound.

However i am not able to do any of them even from the FCM console and neither from my laravel backend for which i am using Kreit.

The notifications are working and reaching the device as i validate them with firebase first. I get the notifications BUT they are the discrete ones and the sound does happen BUT no banner.

I have read some post that say you need to tinker with the manifest file and do something with android side of things. I am quite lost.

Here is my entire payload on laravel which is working properly just not Heads Up.

```
        $deviceToken = 'chcC_kgZHrI0VpqpdPClE8XGJzwWV';
        // $name = 'Notification name'; //FIX_THIS_SOON figure this out soon
        $topic = 'Notification topic'; //FIX_THIS_SOON figure this out soon
        $condition = 'Notification condition'; //FIX_THIS_SOON figure this out soon
        $notificationTitle = 'Package is being delivered';
        // $notificationBody = 'Your order 9847GH8409 is on it\'s way to you.'; //version 1
        // $notificationBody = 'Your order 9847GH8419 is on it\'s way to you.'; //version 2
        $notificationBody = 'Your order 9847GH8429 is on its way to you.'; //version 3
        $notificationIcon = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'; //
        $notificationImageUrl = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/';
        $notificationPriority = 'high';
        $apnsPayloadBadge = 42; //FIX_THIS_SOON
        $analyticsLabel = 'some-analytics-label'; //FIX_THIS_SOON

        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#notification
        $notificationPayload = [
            'title' => $notificationTitle,
            'body' => $notificationBody,
            //'image' => $notificationImageUrl,
        ];

        //payload needs to be configured from the parent function as an array, don't pass individual elements
        $data = [
            'click_action' => 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            'action' => 'new_notification',
            'priority' => 'high', //does this need to be here?
            'sound' => 'default', //does this need to be here?
            'notification_id' => '888888888',
            'notification_uid' => '1111-2222-3333-4444',
            'notification_foreignUID' => '5555-6666-7777-8888',
            'notification_foreignUID_type' => 'user',
            'notification_title' => $notificationTitle,
            'notification_message' => $notificationBody,
            'notification_asset_type' => 'image',
            'notification_image' => 'http://127cf52a.ngrok.io/storage/images_products/860a6ac4-bd66-4c3b-b07f-450f7cdcc007_2020-01-20_15-15-21_0001.jpg',
            'notification_icon' => null,
            'notification_account_type' => 'client',
            'notification_read_status' => '0',
            'notification_status' => 'active',
            'notification_created_at' => '2020-03-29 02:09:00',
            'notification_updated_at' => '2020-03-29 02:09:00',
        ];

        $androidTtl = '3600s';

        $androidCollapseKey = '';

        $androidRestrictedPackageName = '';

        $androidNotificationPayload = [
            'title' => $notificationTitle,
            'body' => $notificationBody,
            // 'icon' => 'string',
            // 'color' => 'string',
            'sound' => 'default',
            // 'tag' => 'string',
            'click_action' => 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            // 'body_loc_key' => 'string',
            /* 'body_loc_args' => [
                'string'
            ], */
            // 'title_loc_key' => 'string',
            /* 'title_loc_args' => [
                'string'
            ], */
            'channel_id' => 'Notifications',
            // 'ticker' => 'string',
            'sticky' => false, //When set to false or unset, the notification is automatically dismissed when the user clicks it in the panel. When set to true, the notification persists even when the user clicks it.
            // 'event_time' => 'string',
            'local_only' => true,
            'notification_priority' => 'priority_high', //also priority_max
            'default_sound' => true,
            'default_vibrate_timings' => true,
            'default_light_settings' => true,
            /* 'vibrate_timings' => [
                'string'
            ], */
            // 'visibility' => 'private',
            // 'notification_count' => integer,
            /* 'light_settings' => {
                "color" => {
                    object (Color)
                },
                "light_on_duration": string,
                "light_off_duration": string
            }, */ //i can't get to write the object properly
            // 'image' => $notificationImageUrl
        ];

        $androidFcmOptions = [
            'analytics_label' => $analyticsLabel //optional
        ];

        $webPushHeaders = [
            'Urgency' => 'high',
        ];

        $webPushFcmOptions = [
            // 'link' => '',
            'analytics_label' => $analyticsLabel //optional
        ];

        $apnsHeaders = [
            'apns-priority' => '10',
        ];

        $apnsPayload = [
            'aps' => [
                'alert' => [
                    'title' => $notificationTitle,
                    'body' => $notificationBody,
                ],
                'badge' => $apnsPayloadBadge,
            ],
        ];

        $apnsFcmOptions = [
            // 'image' => '',
            'analytics_label' => $analyticsLabel //optional
        ];

        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidconfig
        $androidSettings = [
            'ttl' => $androidTtl,
            'priority' => $notificationPriority,
            // 'collapse_key' => $androidCollapseKey,
            // 'restricted_package_name' => $androidRestrictedPackageName,
            'notification' => $androidNotificationPayload,
            'data' => $data,
            'fcm_options' => $androidFcmOptions,
        ];

        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#apnsconfig
        $apnsSettings = [
            'headers' => $apnsHeaders,
            'payload' => $apnsPayload,
            'fcm_options' => $apnsFcmOptions,
        ];

        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#webpushconfig
        $webpushSettings = [
            'headers' => $webPushHeaders,
            'notification' => $androidNotificationPayload,
            'data' => $data,
            'fcm_options' => $webPushFcmOptions,
        ];

        //hide fcm_options if you are leaving it empty
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#fcmoptions
        $fcmOptions = [
            'analytics_label' => $analyticsLabel //optional
        ];

        //DELETE_SOON
        Log::channel('merlin_debug')->info('option 3 222');

        $message = new RawMessageFromArray([
            'token' => $deviceToken,
            // 'name' => $name,
            // 'topic' => $topic,
            // 'condition' => $condition,
            'notification' => $notificationPayload,
            'data' => $data,
            'android' => $androidSettings,
            'apns' => $apnsSettings,
            'webpush' => $webpushSettings,
            'fcm_options' => $fcmOptions
        ]);

        $messaging = app('firebase.messaging');

        $messaging->send($message);
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. It is fixed?

Comment: Yes i was able to fix it. Are you using Laravel as a backend?

Comment: @NicolasZein how did you fix it? I have the same issue, also using Laravel. Please answer you question you posted.